# Any example of an unsatisfiable integer program with non constant Rank Lower bounds for LS+ cuts but with short LS+ refutations?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, open-problem, integer-programming, proof-complexity

Assume we want to refute an unsatisfiable CNF.  We can interpret it as an integer program, thus a refutation can be done by applying Lovasz-Schrijver semidefinite cuts ($LS_{+}$ cuts) to its linear relaxation until the polytope is empty.

For a polytope $P$ we consider $N_{+}(P)$ to be the polytope where all possible $LS_{+}$ cuts have been further applied.  We can always iterate the operator $N_{+}$ until the resulting polytope is empty.  The number of iterations required to reach the empty polytope is called the *rank* of the polytope.

Since each iteration increases the number of facet of a polynomial factor, a non constant number of iterations is out of question.

In the case of Gomory-Chvátal cuts, the usual PHP formula requires rank $\Omega(\log n)$, but there exists a refutation of polynomial size.  Such refutation essentially produces the empty polytope using only a small number of the facets from each iteration.

**My question is:** does there exist a similar example for $LS_{+}$ cuts, i.e. a case where an short refutation exists but the rank is large?

**Update**: The following paper shows (among other things) that a tautology with short refutation and linear rank would separate Tree-Like LS+ from general LS+ refutations.

Toniann Pitassi and Nathan Segerlind, "[Exponential Lower Bounds and Integrality Gaps for Tree-like Lovasz-Schrijver Procedures](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Papers/soda.ps)", SODA, 2009.

Comment: I assume that LS cuts are Lovasz-Schrijver cuts ? might be helpful to clarify.

Comment: So basically you look for a hard tautology (different from PHP) that separates tree-like and dag-like LS+ ? Am I correct ?

Comment: I don't know the status of rank size trade-offs in LS+. Of course a positive answer to this question is a step towards the separation you mention.  For context: consider PHP under Cutting Planes with Gomory-Chvátal cuts; in this case the short refutation is polynomial size and tree-like while the rank in $\Omega(\log n)$. This is non trivial since usually rank $r$ implies $n^r$ upper bounds, both in GC and LS.  Notice that as far as I know even such upper bound is unknown for LS+.  My question can be rephrased like: "given that such upper bound exists, it is optimal?".

Comment: Apparently in SODA 2009, Pitassi and Segerlind proved rank/size trade-off for tree-like and LS and tree-like LS+. Thus Iddo's comment is completely correct.

Comment: Do you want to update your question? (I have added the link to Toni and Nathan's paper.) Also if this is an open problem, we should add the [open-problem] tag.